# Incremental Pagination in Scrapy / Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I came across a paging difficulty with Scrapy.
I usually used the following code successfully

```
next_page = response.xpath("//div//div[4]//ul[1]//li[10]//a[1]//@href").extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

It turns out that in this attempt, I came across a website that uses blocks of 5 pages. See image below.

[image]

So, after capturing the first 5 pages, Scrapy jumps to the penultimate page (526).

The paging structure follows the following logic:

[https://www.example.com-1-data.html](https://www.exemplo.com-1-data.html)

And it increases numerically.
Can anyone help me with the incremental query (based on the example address) for this pagination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to pagination optimal approach really depends on what sort of pagination is being used.

If you:

- know url page format
  e.g. that url argument `page` indicates what page your on
- know total amount of pages

Then you can schedule all pages at once:

```
def parse_listings_page1(self, response):
    """
    here parse first page, schedule all other pages at once!
    """
    # e.g. 'http://shop.com/products?page=1'
    url = response.url
    # e.g. 100
    total_pages = int(response.css('.last-page').extract_first())

    # schedule every page at once! 
    for page in range(2, total_pages + 1):
        page_url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'page', page)
        yield Request(page_url, self.parse_listings)
    # don't forget to also parse listings on first page!
    yield from self.parse_listings(response)


def parse_listings(self, response):
    for url in response.css('.listing::attr(href)'):
        yield Request(url, self.parse_product)
```

The huge benefits of this approach is speed - here you can take of async logic and crawl all pages simultaneously!

Alternatively.

If you:

- don't know anything other than next page url is on the page

Then you have to schedule the pages synchronously 1 by 1:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for product in response.css('.product::attr(href)'):
        yield Request(product, self.parse_product)

    next_page = response.css('.next-page::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield Request(next_page, self.parse)
    else:
        print(f'last page reached: {response.url}')
```

In your example your using the second syncronous approach and your fears here are unfounded, you just have to ensure your xpath selector selects the right page.

Answer (score 2):

For extract all data from all navigation pages, you can use Scrapy [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) in rules.

**1 Use RegExp**

```
rules = {
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.*part-of-url/page-nav/page.*'), callback='parse_page', follow=True)
}
```

**2 Use XPath**

```
rules = {
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths='//ul[@class="nav-block"]'), callback='parse_page', follow=True)
    }
```

Comment: This option is very interesting. Thank you.